# Splitting UNC path into components

Tags: powershell

I have a list of UNC paths to which I need to do various tests and manipulations.

I'm using System.Uri to split the host and the path string and it works. The only trouble is that the absolute path property returned has swapped the back slashes for forward slashes. When I want to join the UNC back together I would need to do some yucky string manipulation to change the slashes back(slashes).

I know I could use regex and other stuff but I'm always looking for a cleaner and more elegant way. Sometimes you need to do string manipulation but Powershell has taught me to seek methods and object.

I'm wondering if there is another/cleaner way to extract the path components than using regex vs System.Uri

Ideally I'm looking for all Path Components and not just replacing slashes.

```
$TestPath = "\\hostname.domain.com\share_24_$\folder"
$X = New-Object System.Uri -ArgumentList $TestPath

$X.Host
hostname.domain.com

$X.AbsolutePath
/share_24_$/folder
```

Comment: It's 'yucky string manipulation', but if you have the path with forward slashes in `$foo`, you could always do ``$foo = ($foo -split '/') -join '\' ``

Comment: I would use $x.AbsolutePath.Replace("/","\") because it just looks cleaner to me

Comment: Thanks for suggestions about replace. I've edited my original question. I'm looking for all components. Swapping slashes is easy. I'm looking to get an object that has all bits of the path. Something like resolve-path but that works with UNC

Comment: If you are wanting to get all the path components back, then wouldn't you still need to join these to make a full path? BTW you can get the segments using $x.Segments but the slashes are still the other way.

Comment: Try `$X.Segments -replace '/', '' -join '\'`

Comment: I like `-Split` for this: `($testpath -Split "\\\\?") | Select-Object -skip 1`. Then you can join or grab the array indexes as you see fit. You "could" just make your own object class for this and set up properties as you see fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few things to consider here before I found my ultimate solution.

First I had to do a replace on the AbsolutePath. There are at least 3 ways of doing that as demonstrated above.

The second thing that was a bit of a gotcha that I didn't notice at first was that AbsolutePath is URL encoded. You don't notice with simple paths but I had a few with spaces in them the caused issues. 
I may end up making my own function to return a path object in future. Thanks for all the suggestions.

I ended up doing this.

```
[string]$ThisTargetPath = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode( $URI.AbsolutePath.Replace('/','\') )
```